# Javascript: Where is the syntax error?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I am still learning this... so am kinda  a noob.

I am getting a syntax error on this (in firefox)

```
get_domain_name: function ()
```

A little confused...

My full code:
http://pastebin.com/g9ZGVtDa

The exact message firefox is giving me is:

> Error: syntax error Line: 76, Column: 29 Source Code:
>   get_domain_name: function ()

Comment: Looks like you're biting off more than you can chew here if you can't find this.

Comment: I know I am but little choice... and a long (boring) story.

Comment: It looks like you're blindly pasting together code snippets you don't understand, and then wonder why they fall apart at the seams. _Learn the language first_. That is, read an actual description of how the programming language works, instead of pre-digested "how do I do X" recipes.

Comment: It is downvoted not because you still have to learn but because the type of question is not suitable. Because you have soo much to learn it's too broad to deal with here. This is not a teaching site and having others spot and fix your errors is not an effective way to learn

Answer (score 4):

```
var object = { //This is object literal notation
    get_domain_name: function () {} 
};

function fn() {  //This is probably what you need
    var get_domain_name = function() {};
}
```

The difference is that the former will let you call `object.get_domain_name()` while the latter will let you call `get_domain_name()`, but only inside `fn`.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the function incorrectly. Javascript functions are declared [as described on Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/function.html):

```
function myFunctionName(){
    ...
}
```

So your functions would instead of being named like above, be named:

```
function get_domain_name(){
    ...
}
function filterUrl(){
    ...
}
```